# How to get correct type and nullability information for enum fields using jOOQ's metadata API?

Tags: postgresql, enums, jooq

I'm trying to use jOOQ's metadata API, and most columns behave the way I'd expect, but enum columns seem to be missing type and nullability information somehow.

For example, if I have a schema defined as:

```sql
CREATE TYPE public.my_enum AS ENUM (
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz'
);

CREATE TABLE public.my_table (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    name text,
    my_enum_column public.my_enum NOT NULL,
);
```

The following test passes:

```kotlin
// this is Kotlin, but hopefully pretty easy to decipher
test("something fishy going on here") {
    val jooq = DSL.using(myDataSource, SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
    val myTable = jooq.meta().tables.find { it.name == "my_table" }!!

    // This looks right...
    val createdAt = myTable.field("created_at")!!
    createdAt.dataType.nullability() shouldBe Nullability.NOT_NULL
    createdAt.dataType.typeName shouldBe "timestamp with time zone"

    // ...but none of this seems right
    val myEnumField = myTable.field("my_enum_column")!!
    myEnumField.dataType.typeName shouldBe "other"
    myEnumField.dataType.nullability() shouldBe Nullability.DEFAULT
    myEnumField.dataType.castTypeName shouldBe "other"
    myEnumField.type shouldBe Any::class.java
}
```

1. It's telling me that enum columns have `Nullability.DEFAULT` regardless of whether they are null or not null. For other types, `Field.dataType.nullability` will vary depending on whether the column is null or not null, as expected.
2. For any enum column, the `type` is `Object` (`Any` in Kotlin), and the `dataType.typeName` is "other". For non-enum columns, `dataType.typeName` gives me the correct SQL for the type.

I'm also using the jOOQ code generator, and it generates the correct types for enum columns. That is, it creates an enum class and uses that as the type for the corresponding fields, which are marked as not-nullable. The generated code for this field looks something like (reformatted to avoid long lines):

```java
public final TableField<MyTableRecord, MyEnum> MY_ENUM_COLUMN =
    createField(
        DSL.name("my_enum_column"),
        SQLDataType.VARCHAR
            .nullable(false)
            .asEnumDataType(com.example.schema.enums.MyEnum.class),
        this,
        ""
    )
```

So it appears that jOOQ's code generator has the type information, but how can I access the type information via the metadata API?

I'm using `postgres:11-alpine` and `org.jooq:jooq:3.14.11`.

### Update 1

I tried testing this with `org.jooq:jooq:3.16.10` and  `org.jooq:jooq:3.17.4`. They seem to fix the nullability issue, but the datatype is still "other", and the type is still `Object`. So it appears the nullability issue was a bug in jOOQ. I'll file an issue about the type+datatype.

### Update 2

This is looking like it may be a bug, so I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14043).

Comment: Sounds similar to https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14005. Maybe fancy reporting it here? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

Comment: @LukasEder Sure, I'll do that, but that issue is talking about the generated code being incorrect. In my case, the generated code is correct. I added an example snippet to the question to illustrate this. It's only when I use the metadata API that I get "nullable other" for all enums columns.